# How do I fix my navbar in bootstrap vue to be in centre?

Tags: vue.js, gif, bootstrap-vue

How can I put my navbar component in the centre? This is my first time doing this I got most of it ok but I just can't seem to fix this problem so it doesn't look weird

```
<template>
  <div class="container">
    <header>
      <h1>GIF'S APP</h1>
      <form>
        <span class="font-semibold mr-2 text-left flex-auto text-white">Search for the coolest gifs</span>
        <div>
          <b-nav-form>
            <b-input-group>
              <b-form-input id="input-small" size="sm" type="text" v-model="search" />
              <b-button class="btn-success" type="button" v-on:click="searchNewGifs()">Search</b-button>
              <div class="gifs--container">
                <Gif v-for="gif in gifs" v-bind:key="gif.id" v-bind:data="gif"></Gif>
              </div>
              <b-button
                class="btn-success"
                type="button"
                v-if="!stopNextPage"
                v-on:click="getNextPage()"
              >Next Page</b-button>
            </b-input-group>
          </b-nav-form>
        </div>
      </form>
    </header>
  </div>
</template>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use class `mx-auto` horizontal centre and class `my-auto` for vertical centre and if you you want to make horizontal and vertical centre use `m-auto` and NOTE: very important is that the parent have the style `dispaly: flex` and the class available for that is `d-flex`.